# Auto Checked Checkbox value using vue.js

Tags: laravel, vue.js

On my edit page I'm trying to make my checkbox auto checked based on the permissions that I already assigned to my roles, I don't know how to make it work. Any idea? Currently with my code I'm getting unchecked checkbox with the list of all my permissions.

`Edit.blade`

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    permissionsSelected: []
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="from-group">
  <div class="checkbox-group" v-model="permissionsSelected">
    @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
    <div class="field">
      <input type="checkbox" value="{{$permission->id}}" name="permissions[]">{{$permission->display_name}}
    </div>
    @endforeach

  </div>
```

Comment: Check the "multiple checkboxes" part: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Checkbox You would need to change your markup a bit, and in order to auto check, to populate the `permissionsSelected` array with the appropiate checkbox values.

Comment: bro. my checkbox value is i'm getting it on my roles which is stored in my database how to pull it out?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `v-model="permissionsSelected"` from div and add it to each checkbox:

```html
<div class="from-group">
  <div class="checkbox-group">
    @foreach ($permissions as $permission)
    <div class="field">
      <input
        type="checkbox" 
        value="{{$permission->id}}"
        name="permissions[]" 
        v-model="permissionsSelected"> {{$permission->display_name}}
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Also make sure your data setup is a function returning an object:

```
data () {
  return {
    permissionsSelected: []
  }
}
```

Comment: how to return my data on the permissionSelected since my data is base on my database how to pull it out ? meaning permission_id +user_id?

Comment: Selected permissions will populate `permissionsSelected` array. You don't need to do anything for this to work.

Comment: var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data () {
      return {
        permissionsSelected: []
      }
    }
  });     not working bro.